Ideal method to do image similarity comparison between two binary images - Tactile Maps
I have a task for image similarity comparisons between two binary images of tactile maps (maps for the visually impaired to map out an area). The goal is to have an output score of how similar the two images are. The score should be derived from the similarity of the following measures: the length of line segments, the angles between segments, the correct nodes/intersection points, the local and global structure.
Here are examples of a paired image to compare:
Hand drawn image of a tactile map
Template image of a tactile map
A hurdle is that one image is human hand-drawn which has some line quality discrepancies (curvilinear and jagged edges) which we would ideally want to ignore and focus mainly on the overall segment's angle, length, and direction.
It would be best if the method is scale and rotational invariant as well.
Method process attempted in Matlab to try and detect the line segments:

Convert both images to grayscale

Apply Guassian smoothing

Apply 'Canny' edge detection

Use bwmorph() to thin the edges so line quality is consistent across images

Use hough(), houghpeaks(), and houghlines() to detect the line segments


This method is having trouble detecting the line segments in the hand drawing images as the line segments are completely different varying in line quality.
If this worked and detected the lines well, the next step would be to compare the detected line segments within quadrants for local structure for the length, angles between segments, and intersection points between the hand drawn tactile map and the template tactile map.

you can forget about that approach. this will need some level of AI/ML.
